# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to integrate admob to my flutter application using google_mobile_ads: ^1.2.0 plugin. But it is giving me this error:

```dart
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel
plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod
    (http://localhost:54890/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

I cant find the solution for this. I have been trying to find a solution for a month.  I have tried all solutions recommended on the websites related to this. But no single one helped me. Could anyone please help me figure it out.
Here is my main source code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
    return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isBannerReady = false;
  late BannerAd myBanner;

  Future<void> loadAd() {
    myBanner = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
      size: AdSize.banner,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          isBannerReady = true;
          print('Ad loaded.');
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('Ad failed to load: $error');
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('Ad opened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('Ad closed.'),
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) => print('Ad impression.'),
      ),
    );
    return myBanner.load();
  }

  @override
  didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    loadAd();
  }

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$_counter',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          isBannerReady
              ? Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: myBanner.size.width.toDouble(),
                    height: myBanner.size.height.toDouble(),
                    child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testad">
   <application
        android:label="testad"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

what is interesting is that when i add

```dart
MobileAds.instance.initialize();
```

in my main method
instead of

```dart
Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
    return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }
```

the error message is changing to

```dart
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method _init on channel
plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod
    (http://localhost:54890/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method MobileAds#initialize on channel
plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod
    (http://localhost:54890/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method loadBannerAd on channel
plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
    at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod
    (http://localhost:54890/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:54890/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

Comment: what channel are you in?

Comment: I am in the stable channel

Comment: Please look at my answer here, it might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73427512/4559963

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Please make sure you are **running on a mobile device or emulator**.
I do not think these methods works when running with Chrome, Edge or Windows.

(I also did other things to make sure the project was cleaned, restarted computer, cloned git-repo again etc. But I believe this was the solution for the missing methods)